# Multiply elements of the array by 3 weighting factors and repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want to be able to multiply each array element by 3 different weighting factors.

User input = `[24,3,0, 56,43,34]`

Output = `24x7,3x3,0x1 + 56x7, 43x3, 34x0`.. and repeat so basically at every 3 elements of the array a multiplication by 7, then 3, then 0 occurs.

It would look something like this:

For every array element multiply each array weighting factor and repeat when it gets to 3rd element

```
function multiplyWeightFact(input){

 const weighting = [7,3,1]

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length ; i++) {
    console.log( input[0] * weighting[0])
    console.log( input[1] * weighting[1])
    console.log( input[3] * weighting[2])
    break
}
for (let index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {
  console.log( input[4] * weighting[0])
  console.log( input[5] * weighting[1])
  console.log( input[6] * weighting[2])
  break 
}
  }
```

input from user  = `[24,3,0, 56,43,34]`

and it continues if we have an array with lets say 100 numbers..

The output needs to be something like:

`resultOutput = 374 when input is [24,10]`

Of course the above function is not sustainable so any better way to do this?

Comment: what output do you want?

Comment: Output = 24x7,3x3,0x1 + 56x7, 43x3, 34x0 ( these are example numbers but basically each element in the array staring by element 0 has to multiply by 7, then by 3, then by 0 then + the next 3 elements in the array which are again multiplied by 7, then 3, then 0 and it continues in repeat mode 3elementsxweightingfactor7,3,1 - so the output is the sum of those elements multiplied by weighting factors in repeat mode

Comment: You haven't really answered the question. What should the output look like for `input = [24, 3, 0, 56, 43, 34]; weighting = [7, 3, 1]`? Is it a string like in your comment (`24x7,3x3,0x1 + 56x7, 43x3, 34x0`)? Or is it an array with the numbers? Then what rule should they follow? Or is it a single number (the result of a math operation)? -> [mcve]

Comment: look like a number - resultOutput = 374 when input is [24,10]

Comment: Please add this to your question. As you can see all answers so far don't return the expected result, because you haven't mentioned it _in your question_.

Answer (score 2):

You could map by taking an index and the remainder operator with the length of `weighting`.

```js
const
    multiplyBy = weighting => (v, i) => v * weighting[i % weighting.length],
    array = [24, 3, 0, 56, 43, 34],
    weighting = [7, 3, 1],
    result = array.map(multiplyBy(weighting));

console.log(...result);
```

With `x`

```js
const
    multiplyBy = weighting => (v, i) => `${v}x${weighting[i % weighting.length]}`,
    array = [24, 3, 0, 56, 43, 34],
    weighting = [7, 3, 1],
    result = array.map(multiplyBy(weighting));

console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array elements and use the modulo operator to multiply with according to the position the right factor.

**Modulo Explanation**
Calculates the remainder.

```
const weighting = [7, 3, 1] // Instead of 3 weighting.length

1. 0 % 3 = 0 = Array Element = 7
2. 1 % 3 = 1 = Array Element = 3
3. 2 % 3 = 2 = Array Element = 1
4. 3 % 3 = 0 = Array Element = 7

And again ...
```

```js
function multiplyWeightFact(input) {

  const weighting = [7, 3, 1]


  for (let index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {

    input[index] *= weighting[index % weighting.length];


  }
  return input;
}
let input = [5,4,3,2,1]

console.log(multiplyWeightFact(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the input and multiply it by the weight based on it's index. We can then use [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to keep the index within the range of the weight array.

```js
function multiplyWeightFact(input, weight){  
  return input.map((num, index) => num * weight[index % weight.length]);
}

const weight = [7, 3, 0];
const input = [24, 3, 0, 56, 43, 34];

const result = multiplyWeightFact(input, weight);

console.log(result);
```